# Is this site down or is it just me?

Tags: code-golf, internet

### Challenge

The challenge is simple, using http://isup.me, determine whether an inputted website is up or down.

If the site is up, you should return a truthy value and if the site is down, you should return a falsey value.

### Rules

The input will be a web address such as `stackexchange.com` or `google.co.uk`. The input will never have `http://`, `https://` etc. at the start of the string, but may have `www.` or `codegolf.` at start etc.

You should use the site `isup.me/URL` where URL is the input.

When a site is up, it will look like:

[image]

http://isup.me/codegolf.stackexchange.com

If a site is down, it will look like:

[image]

http://isup.me/does.not.exist

URL shorteners are disallowed apart from isup.me.

### Example inputs

Probably up (depending on current circumstances):

```
google.de
codegolf.stackexchange.com
worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com
tio.run
store.nascar.com
isup.me
```

Will be down:

```
made.up.com
fake.com.us
why.why.why.delilah
store.antarcticrhubarbassociation.an
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: If URL shorteners aren't allowed, should we use downforeveryoneorjustme.com or isup.me ?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien No, I'll make an exception for isup.me

Comment: By the way: "made.up.co.uk" is actually up.

Comment: @GiantTree Hmm... technically up but doesn't exist.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Irrelevant

Comment: I've just registered `fake.com.us` to mess with your test cases!

Comment: @PierreArlaud I mean, it's just a registrar page.

Comment: @Erik isup.me still registers it as up though

Comment: But what if `isup.me` is down?

Comment: @Oks Are you sure it's not just you?

Comment: Recommended test case: `isup.me`. It returns a result other than what, say, `google.com` may return.

Comment: @Okx Thanks, that's a good one

Comment: I have just notified Tom Jones.  He's shouting at his agent right now.

Comment: mabye add a test case for something like `qweasdzxc` with no `.tld` - returns different results. I'd say answers should only need to take valid web addresses into account though..

Answer (score 16):

## sh (+ curl + grep), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```sh
curl -L isup.me/$1|grep ^I
```

Outputs via exit status (0 for up, 1 for down).  Looks for an `I` at the beginning of a line, which matches when the domain is up (even for the special case of [isup.me/isup.me](http://isup.me/isup.me)).

Comment: `curl -L isup.me/$1|grep u!` saves 1 byte. This assumes that ! is not a valid character in the domain name.

Comment: Is `0` truthy in sh?

Comment: `0` is indeed truthy in sh, with all nonzero values being falsy. Also, IMO it's really nice that the sh version is so short, since it's absolutely the right language for this task even without considering golfing.

Comment: That said this will fail on something like spthissitedoesntexist.invalid

Comment: @Score_Under it does work for that domain. the /sp doesn't match the sp in the domain.

Comment: It matches on my machine. It matches this bit: `<a href="http://spthissitedoesntexist.invalid" class="domain">spthissitedoesntexist.invalid</a>` Specifically it matches inside the `href`.

Comment: @Score_Under oh, you're right. I didn't notice the / from http://.

Comment: @Score_Under Fixed.

Comment: @stanri I would not accept `grep u!` because the challenge specifies the result must be truthy on domains that are up.

Answer (score 5):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 44 bytes

```
['http://isup.me/'\+[CS'!'eq sum 2=out]curl]
```

Asynchronous function that outputs `0` if the site is not up, and any other number greater than `0` if it is up.

Example a:

```
['http://isup.me/'\+['s u'split#'1-put]curl] @:isup

'Is google up?' put 'google.com' isup
```

Output (probably): `Is google up? 1`

Comment: Can you add linked to Stacked GH page?

Comment: @Downgoat Done.

Comment: If this is checking for an occurrence of `s u`, note that this occurs on any input beginning with `u` (whether up or down).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Better example: `'Is example.com up?' put 'example.com' isup` output (not just probably but surely): `Is example.com up? 1`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer How is that a better example ?

Answer (score 5):

## Kotlin REPL - <strike>131 108 106 93 79 55 53 64</strike> 63 bytes

First try at Kotlin golfing.
Expects the website in a variable or value named `a`.

<strike>*Now with reduced whitespace.*

*Who said "loo" isn't enough?*

*Fixed and shorter, doesn't rely on http://isup.me anymore.*

*No need to open the connection ourselves, just get the stream of data (or not)*

*The task was to use http://isup.me, right? Also: `<` is not a valid character in a URL.*

*Now works with `isup.me` as the website*</strike>
*Now reads the website as a line, because one can't assume a variable to contain the website.*

```
"m h" !in java.net.URL("http://isup.me/"+readLine()).readText()
```

Reads one line containing just the website.
Checks for the `m h` part of `from here` that is sent when a site is down.

Returns "true" or "false" respectively.

---

## As a Lambda - <strike>172 120 118 99 85 67</strike> 66 bytes

```
{a:String->"m h" !in java.net.URL("http://isup.me/$a").readText()}
```

Can be invoked directly:

```
{ ... }("google.com")
```

Comment: forgive me if I'm wrong, but couldn't this be converted to a lambda fairly easily?

Comment: @NickClifford sure, but it would actually be longer due to the argument and type definition (15 chars because type inference doesn't work here)

Comment: I don't know the language, but it seems like you are checking to see if "loo" is in the returned text. Is it not the case that this text also returns the (variable) site name? And if it is, does that mean you get false negatives for sites like loo.com?

Comment: @Cole you are definitely right, I completely forgot about this (I was only testing Google and the fake website). I will update the code next morning (it's 2am where I am currently)

Comment: This one will fail on sites with `loo` in the name. `electric.boogaloo` doesn't exist but the string `loo` will be in the output there.

Comment: I updated the code, shortened it a bit and use a similar method to the `curl` solutions.

Comment: maybe `.openStream()` instead of `openConnection().connect()`?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thanks, that saves a few more characters.

Comment: Yeah, I used the same in Java answer below.

Comment: Well, I re-read the challenge and the goal is to use the proxy service `isup.me`, not testing it yourself. So I deleted my answer and yours is invalid too :(

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire you are right. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Fixed it! It's even shorter thanks to extensions in Kotlin.

Comment: Fix for isup.me as website

Comment: This is invalid, as you can't just assume the input is in a variable.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer updated the REPL part; the Lambda is still valid as it uses its argument.

Comment: In kotlin, is `"http://isup.me/${readLine()}"` not interchangeable with `"http://isup.me/"+readLine()`? If so, the latter is 2 bytes shorter.

Comment: @Score_Under it is. Thanks, I definitely use template strings too often.

Comment: The challenge specifies “If the site is up, you should return a truthy value”, but you return false.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg, you are absolutely right. I'll fix that.

Comment: While the challenge does specify truthy-falsey, [the meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/what-outputs-should-i-allow-for-decision-problems) seems to be for two distinct outputs (or possibly one distinct vs. everything else), so it would be arguable to map `True` to down and `False` to up.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3   <strike>141</strike> <strike>133</strike> <strike>113</strike> <strike>192</strike> 141 bytes

Requires [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) (including webdriver) for python.

*Thanks to @cairdcoinheringaahing for reducing 42 bytes!*  
*Thanks to @V.Courtois for pointing out a simple fix!*

```python
from selenium import*
d=webdriver.Firefox();d.get("http://isup.me/"+input());print("up"in d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/p[1]"))
```

Prints `1` if site is up and running, else prints `0`.

Ungolfed version:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
urlToTest = "www.f.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/"+urlToTest)
res = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/p[1]")
print(1 if "up" in res.text else 0)
```

Comment: They said isup.me is fine in the comments; you can win some bytes :)

Comment: -1 This is a snippet. Full programs or functions are required and input cannot be assumed in a variable (such as `t`). Also, you can golf the print statement to `print("up"in r.text)`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Okay, will make those changes, thank you! This is my second answer, so I didn't know whether to post a snippet or a full fledged program. So I posted both.

Comment: [141 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoMwEEDRfU8h2ZhYSCjdVYSuegkRqc1YB5rJECetnj51/R@fd1kiXUuZUwzVCh8gzKHCwDFJc/LdDyaf8AvJPjDBHDdtWm/fIFotInxzDtfMNoBTZyTOoo1pOSEdILNCqrydkfx4rAOQjNM@bvyURSvnmv6OvqtfkeRI9eC4vwzKmFL@)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 or 3 with Requests (<s>70</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes)

```
from requests import*;lambda u:"u. "in get("http://isup.me/"+u).text
```

<s>1 byte shaved: `"u. "` → `" u"`</s> Nope, not a valid optimisation.
1 byte shaved: `__import__('requests').` → `from requests import*;`

This is now really a REPL-only piece of code, and after running this line the function will be named `_`.

Comment: Syntax error at the end (probably a stray `)`).

Comment: Fails for inputs starting with `u`.

Comment: Using `from requests import*` and `get` is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: it is not REPL-only, it's allowed to answer with unnamed functions (lambdas in python)

Comment: It is an unnamed function, but the script as a whole can't be used as an expression (since it uses `import`), so I think it's safer to just call it a REPL line.

Comment: @Score_Under yes it is accepted

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>74</s> 66 bytes

```js
f=s=>fetch('//isup.me/'+s).then(r=>r.text()).then(t=>/u!/.test(t))
```

Thanks to @Shaggy, who brought to my attention that a resolved promise counts as output.

Problem with this solution that it will throw a CORS error unless I test it on a page that's already at `isup.me`. But currently, that gets redirected to `downforeveryoneorjustme.com`

Older version:


```
f=s=>fetch('//isup.me/'+s).then(r=>r.text()).then(t=>alert(t.match(/u!/)))
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `alert` and just return the Promise. See [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/58974). I think you might also be able to make a saving with `/u!/.test(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
"isup.me/ÿ".w#214è'‚‰Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fKbO4tEAvN1X/8H4lvXJlI0OTwyvUHzXMetSwIfD/fwA)

Unfortunately `"isup.me/ÿ".w§„ uå` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
}" u"s'+"http://isup.me/
```

Return `True` if the site is up, `False` otherwise. The input URL must be quoted. That cannot be tested on the online interpreter because `'` is disabled on it for safety reasons; instead you will need a local copy of [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth).

**Explanation**

```
                        Q    # Implicit input
       +"http://isup.me/     # Concatenate "http://isup.me/" with the input
      '                      # Open the URL
     s                       # Concatenate all the lines of the returned HTML page
}" u"                        # Test whether " u" is in the page or not
```

Comment: Fails for inputs starting with `u`.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 32 bytes

```
(iwr isup.me/$args)-notmatch'u!'
```

Comment: Missed your answer before I posted mine sorry! some weird `irm` behavior saved me a bunch on this one. [mine here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129738/59735)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (Lambdabot), 157 bytes

```hs
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import Network.HTTP.Simple
f s=httpLBS(parseRequest_$"http://isup.me/"++s)>>=print.not.isInfixOf"u!".unpack.getResponseBody
```

Unfortunately you can't import `Network.HTTP.Simple` on `tio.run`, the easiest way to test would be to run this script (you'll need [`stack`](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack)):

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --install-ghc --resolver lts-8.19 runghc --package http-conduit

import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ test [ "google.de", "made.up.com"]
  where test url = print ("testing "++url) >> f url

f :: String -> IO ()
f s=httpLBS(parseRequest_$"http://isup.me/"++s)
 >>=print.not.isInfixOf"u!".unpack.getResponseBody
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 25 Bytes

```
!(irm isup.me/$args).html
```

Uses the fact that `Invoke-RestMethod` returns the page with a `.html` property only on failure. (no idea why exactly this happens...)

inverts the line to convert to bool, outputs `True` for a live site or `False` for a down site.

```
PS C:\Users\sweeneyc\Desktop> .\Test-SiteUp.ps1 "connorlsw.com"
True
PS C:\Users\sweeneyc\Desktop> .\Test-SiteUp.ps1 "connorlsw.notawebsite"
False
PS C:\Users\sweeneyc\Desktop> .\Test-SiteUp.ps1 "google.com"
True
PS C:\Users\sweeneyc\Desktop> .\Test-SiteUp.ps1 "isthisreallyasite.com"
False
```

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler `irm` returns plaintext for non-parsable pages, I was going to do a plaintext match so it would have behaved the same as iwr, regardless I guess if it works it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Halovi](https://github.com/BlackCapCoder/halovi), 20 bytes

```
oisup.me/⁰
\p
ye$hd0
```

Outputs `p.` if the site is down, and `e.` if it is up.

Explanation:

```
oisup.me/⁰  ~# Open the concatination of "isup.me/" and arg0
\p          ~# Select first p element
ye$hd0      ~# Edit text with neovim and output result:
            ~#   Go one character before the end of the line and ..
            ~#   delete until beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

## Go, 111 bytes

In typical Go fashion, the shortest method is to shell it out.

```golang
import"os/exec"
func h(a string)bool{return exec.Command("sh","-c","curl -L isup.me/"+a+"|grep ^I").Run()!=nil}
```

Other implementations here: https://play.golang.org/p/8T5HSDQFmC

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 63 bytes

```clj
#(clojure.string/includes?(slurp(str"http://isup.me/"%))"'s j")
```

Checks if the HTML returned by `slurp` contains the string `"'s j"` (as in, "It **'s j**ust you"). I might be able to find a smaller string that's unique to the page, but it would at most save me 2 bytes. It would also potentially make it less accurate. "'s j" isn't going to appear in the markup anywhere except in that one scenario. A string like "u." however could potentially appear in the URL, which would break it.

```clj
(defn is-up? [site]
  (clojure.string/includes?
    (slurp (str "http://isup.me/" site))
    "'s j"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <del>82</del> 78 bytes

```
<?=$i=$argv[1],+!preg_match("/!.*$i/",file_get_contents("http://isup.me/$i"));
```

Example i/o runs:

```
$ php script.php google.com
> google.com1
```

**Example 2**

```
$ php script.php does.not.exist
> does.not.exist0
```

Comment: Almost the shortest solution possible. Empty output is "a falsy value" too, so you can remove the `+`. And with `$argn` instead of `$argv[1]` you could use another 6 (minus 1) bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Nim, 108 bytes

```
import httpclient,strutils
echo newhttpclient().getcontent("//isup.me/"&stdin.readline.string).find("ks ")<0
```

Unfortunate that `strutils` is needed for `contains`.

Learning Nim, tips appreciated!